# Combine array index and their values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array, with elements that I would like to combine into one array. The elements in the array are in no particular order. I'm using PHP.

Here's what I mean by that.

```
//Input - I have this
array(
  0 => array(cat => 3),
  1 => array(dog => 4),
  2 => array(bug => 1),
  3 => array(bug => 5),
  4 => array(dog => 2),
  5 => array(dog => 1)

);

//Output - I want this 
//They are an accumulation of the values above
array(
   cat => 3,
   dog => 7,
   bug => 6

);
```

Comment: You can't have more than one value for the same key in a PHP Array. Where's that "Input" present?

Comment: Your input array is impossible in PHP, any assignment to a pre-existing key *overrides* any previous value. What does your input *actually* look like?

Comment: How did you get the array in the first place ... its not possible

Comment: Are you sure you have that input? PHP arrays do not allow duplicate keys. [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0qd-5vi)

Comment: Sorry! I meant so say that the elements are indexed 0,1,2,3,4,5... before the cat dog ect.

Comment: So, where does the meta information for "cat", "dog", and "bug" come from? How can you tell which element is a cat, dog, or bug?

Comment: @BrianSmith please edit your question with the actual format.

Comment: @BrianSmith, please write the input array in a format that could _actually_ be executed by PHP.

Comment: Voting to close since it looks like OP have absolute no knowledge about PHP and it's basic structures.

Comment: @BrianSmith can you post a [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like many said u cannot have same keys in one array, what u can do is:

```
//create samples
$item = array ();
$item['animal'] = 'cat';
$item['val'] = 10;

//build the array
$items = array ();
array_push ($items,$item);       
// assuming u have some items in the array now u can:
// assuming your array name is $items

$final_array = array ();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $final_array[$item['animal']]+=$item['val'];  
}

//the result is in $final_array
```

Comment: Perfect! just what I was looking for :D

Comment: Thanks for actually answering my question rather than blowing it off by my mistake.

Comment: np, should i restore it to my previous answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_reduce and a closure (works in php 5.3 and above)

```
$res = array_reduce($array, function (&$result, $val) {
      foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
           if (!isset($result[$k])) $result[$k] = 0;
           $result[$k]+= $val;
           return $result;
      }
}, array());
```

Comment: You'd still have to return `$result` every cycle or it's not passed to the next cycle. [Did you try it?](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c51b6a7b08f23ba0682ac2f4aa54c082f608e45) [This one works though.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/24b5aad6182fefa7803dc4c442f94400d5effb1c)

Comment: I stole the array_reduce() idea from you =) so all credits to you.

Answer (score 1):

@Orangepill's answer doesn't actually work for me, and is strange (reduce with no return value and a by-reference).

This one does work:

```
$in = array(
  array('cat' => 3),
  array('dog' => 4),
  array('bug' => 1),
  array('bug' => 5),
  array('dog' => 2),
  array('dog' => 1),
);

$out = array_reduce($in, function($out, $el) {
  @$out[ key($el) ] += reset($el); // Only 1 key + val per element?
  return $out;
}, array());

var_dump($out);
```

The `@` is to suppress the notice for new keys. `NULL + 2 = 2` so that's fine.